# search in numpy array of points (double condition)

Tags: python, numpy

I have array of points:

```
a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,6],[5,6],[7,7],[6,9]])
```

I need to find numbers where one of the number in pair is equal to 6, while other is greater than 3. In my example, I will get 5 and 9. Could you please help me?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to find pairs of numbers and then from that pair extract the number other than 6?

Comment: Exactly! Could it be done in one operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest one liner is probably making use of the `a.all()` or `a.any()` functions.

```py
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,6],[5,6],[7,7],[6,9]])
>>> a[(a==6).any(axis=1) & (a>3).all(axis=1)]
array([[5, 6],
       [6, 9]])
```

From here, if you want to extract the "non-6" elements, the entire solution can be accomplished pretty clean with this two liner:

```
>>> b = a[(a==6).any(axis=1) & (a>3).all(axis=1)]
>>> b[b!=6].flatten()
array([5, 9])
```

The `axis=1` parameter means that we are evaluating the condition over each row. `any` requires any of the elements in the row to satisfy the condition, while `all` requires them all to satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary operations `&` ("AND") and `|` ("OR"):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,6],[5,6],[7,7],[6,9]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 6],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 7],
       [6, 9]])
>>> a[((a[:, 0] == 6) & (a[:, 1] > 3)) | ((a[:, 0] > 3) & (a[:, 1] == 6))]
array([[5, 6],
      [6, 9]])
```

`((a[:, 0] == 6) & (a[:, 1] > 3)) | ((a[:, 0] > 3) & (a[:, 1] == 6))` says:

> Give me a boolean array where (`a[:, 0] == 6` AND `a[:, 1] > 3`) is true OR (`a[:, 0] > 3` AND `a[:, 1] == 6`) is true.

```
>>> ((a[:, 0] == 6) & (a[:, 1] > 3)) | ((a[:, 0] > 3) & (a[:, 1] == 6))
array([False, False,  True, False,  True])
```

Then the resulting array is used as a mask to extract only those values of `a` where the corresponding element of the mask is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following. First, find all pairs containing a 6:

```
a6 = a[[6 in i for i in a]]
```

Next, extract the number accompanying the 6:

```
oth_no = a6[[~(a[[6 in i for i in a]]==6)]]
```

Finally, dispose of numbers smaller or equal to 3:

```
out = oth_no[oth_no>3]
```